# objects in JavaScript , how can I loop to add keys and values to an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to learn objects in js 
can someone explain to me what does these lines do?

```
//   obj[char] >0 ? ++obj[char] : obj[char] = 1
       obj[char] = ++obj[char] || 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's an `obj[char]` greater than `0`, increment the `obj[char]`, otherwise set it to `1`

```
obj[char] > 0 ? ++obj[char] : obj[char] = 1
```

This is basically the same, but uses the [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

```
obj[char] = ++obj[char] || 1;
```

> `expr1 || expr2`  If `expr1` can be converted to true, returns `expr1`; else, returns `expr2`.

It looks like you're trying to create a map of characters with their count.

```js
let obj = { a: 9 };

["a", "b"].forEach((char) => {
  obj[char] > 0 ? ++obj[char] : (obj[char] = 1);
});

console.log(obj); // { "a": 10, "b": 1 }

obj = { a: 9 };

["a", "b"].forEach((char) => {
  obj[char] = ++obj[char] || 1
});

console.log(obj); // { "a": 10, "b": 1 }
```

Comment: I find `obj[char] = (obj[char] || 0) + 1` more intuitive, by the way.

Comment: Actually the way `x = ++x || 1` works is totally crazy, thinking about it. Not only does it reassign `x` _twice_ (`x + 1` would be better than `++x`), but the whole reason this actually works is because `undefined + 1` is `NaN` which is still falsy! No wonder the OP can't wrap their head around it.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is interesting like that :)